# Regular Expression Parsing Key Value Pairs in Namelist Input File

Tags: python, regex, parsing, key-value

I have an input file which is in a Fortran "namelist" format which I would like to parse with python regular expressions.  Easiest way to demonstrate is with a ficticious example:

```
$VEHICLES
 CARS= 1,
 TRUCKS = 0,
 PLAINS= 0, TRAINS = 0,
 LIB='AUTO.DAT',
C This is a comment
C Data variable spans multiple lines
 DATA=1.2,2.34,3.12,
      4.56E-2,6.78,
$END
$PLOTTING
 PLOT=T,
 PLOT(2)=12,
$END
```

So the keys can contain regular variable-name characters as well as parenthesis and numbers.  The values can be strings, boolean (T, F, .T., .F., TRUE, FALSE, .TRUE., .FALSE. are all possible), integers, floating-point numbers, or comma-separated lists of numbers. Keys are connected to their values with equal signs.  Key-Value pairs are separated by commas, but can share a line.  Values can span multiple lines for long lists of numbers.  Comments are any line beginning with a C.  There is generally inconsistent spacing before and after '=' and ','.

I have come up with a working regular expression for parsing the keys and values and getting them into an Ordered Dictionary (need to preserve order of inputs).

Here's my code so far.  I've included everything from reading the file to saving to a dictionary for thoroughness.

```
import re
from collections import OrderedDict

f=open('file.dat','r')
file_str=f.read()

#Compile regex pattern for requested namelist
name='Vehicles'

p_namelist = re.compile(r"\$"+name.upper()+"(.*?)\$END",flags=re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)

#Execute regex on file string and get a list of captured tokens
m_namelist = p_namelist.findall(file_str)

#Check for a valid result
if m_namelist:
    #The text of the desired namelist is the first captured token
    namelist=m_namelist[0]

#Split into lines
lines=namelist.splitlines()

#List comprehension which returns the list of lines that do not start with "C"
#Effectively remove comment lines
lines = [item for item in lines if not item.startswith("C")]

#Re-combine now that comment lines are removed
namelist='\n'.join(lines)

#Create key-value parsing regex
p_item = re.compile(r"([^\s,\=]+?)\s*=\s*([^=]+)(?=[\s,][^\s,\=]+\s*\=|$)",flags=re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)

#Execute regex
items = p_item.findall(namelist)

#Initialize namelist ordered dictionary
n = OrderedDict()

#Remove undesired characters from value    
for item in items:
    n[item[0]] = item[1].strip(',\r\n ')
```

My question is whether I'm going about this correctly.  I realize there is a ConfigParser library, which I have not yet attempted.  My focus here is the regular expression:

```
([^\s,\=]+?)\s*=\s*([^=]+)(?=[\s,][^\s,\=]+\s*\=|$)
```

but I went ahead and included the other code for thoroughness and to demonstrate what I'm doing with it.  For my Regular Expression, because the values can contain commas, and the key-value pairs are also separated by commas, there is no simple way to isolate the pairs.  I chose to use a forward look-ahead to find the next key and "=".  This allows everything between the "=" and the next key to be the value.  Finally, because this doesn't work for the last pair, I threw in "|$" into the forward look-ahead meaning that if another "VALUE=" isn't found, look for the end of the string.  I figured matching the value with [^=]+ followed by a look-ahead was better than trying to match all possible value types.

While writing this question I came up with an alternative Regular Expresson that takes advantage of the fact that numbers are the only value that can be in lists:

```
 ([^\s,\=]+?)\s*=\s*((?:\s*\d[\d\.\E\+\-]*\s*,){2,}|[^=,]+)
```

This one matches either a list of 2 or more numbers with `(?:\s*\d[\d\.\E\+\-]*\s*,){2,}` or anything before the next comma with `[^=,]`.

Are these somewhat messy Regular Expressions the best way to parse a file like this?

Comment: Why are you insisting on using regex here?  Also, why does order matter?  My impression was that fortran namelists aren't ordered..

Comment: I'm building an application for editing input files.  Some of the namelists have hundreds of entries which are typically grouped into logical categories. Also, related or co-dependent inputs are generally listed together so that they can be easily edited together. I want to be able to read in an input file, provide a GUI for editing various parameters, then write it back out in the same order.  I actually already have the GUI and export functionality working (using a hard-coded dataset) and I'm now writing an import function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to develop little more sophisticated parser.

I stumble upon the project on google code hosting that implements very similar parser functionality: [Fortran Namelist parser for Python prog/scripts](http://code.google.com/p/fortran-namelist/) but it was build for little different format.
I played with it a little and updated it to support structure of the format in your example:

Please see my version on gist: 
[Updated Fortran Namelist parser for python https://gist.github.com/4506282](https://gist.github.com/4506282)

I hope this parser will help you with your project.

Here is example output produced by the script after parsing FORTRAN code example:

```
{'PLOTTING': 
    {'par': 
        [OrderedDict([('PLOT', ['T']), ('PLOT(2) =', ['12'])])],
    'raw': ['PLOT=T', 'PLOT(2)=12']},
 'VEHICLES': 
    {'par': 
        [OrderedDict([('TRUCKS', ['0']), ('PLAINS', ['0']), ('TRAINS', ['0']), ('LIB', ['AUTO.DAT']), ('DATA', ['1.2', '2.34', '3.12', '4.56E-2', '6.78'])])],
  'raw': 
                ['TRUCKS = 0',
                  'PLAINS= 0, TRAINS = 0',
                  "LIB='AUTO.DAT'",
                  'DATA=1.2,2.34,3.12',
                  '4.56E-2,6.78']}}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort in this response!  I did end up finding the Fortran Namelist Parser you mentioned and stole some of the regular expressions from it to help determine the data type of the value for each key value pair.  In the end I stuck with my fairly simple regex parsing approach because I understand it.  Your answer though is by all means a robust, tailored solution to my question!  Kudos for your hard work!  Maybe I'll use it eventually to improve my code once I can wrap my head around everything it's doing!

Comment: Thanks, that was very useful ! In my opinion, this is a step up from the previous version of the code.